# Is the union of a closed interval and half closed interval compact?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Is the subset
$$[0, 1]\cup (4, 5] $$
compact in $$(\mathbb{R},d)$$

Comment: A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is compact if, and only if, it is closed and bounded. Is your set closed? Is it bounded?

Comment: no, it is not compact. What did you attempt to answer your question? Which definition and characterization of compactness do you use?

Comment: To add to Mark's comment, you might want to look up the Heine-Borel theorem.

Comment: I use the definition of compact that states any closed and bounded subset is compact. the subset is not closed, so therefore not compact.

Answer (score 2):

If your definition of compactness is "closed and bounded", and your definition of "closed" is that a set contains all its boundary points, than you can look at your example and examine the boundary points and ask yourself if they are in the set.

If your definition of "closed" is the complement of an open set, then take the complement of your set and see if it's open (i.e. by examining boundary points).

If your definition of compactness is "every open cover of the set can be made into a finite subcover", then consider the open cover:
$$(-0.5, 1.5) \cup \left(4+\frac 1k, 5.5\right) \text{ for } k=1,2,3,\ldots$$
Does any finite subfamily of this open cover manage to cover your set?

*Note:* For more information regarding these different definitions of compactness, google the Heine-Borel theorem.

Comment: you should probably use the term finite subfamily rather than a finite subcover, on the last line. Also, you do not consider "open covers of the form" $(-0.5, 1.5) \cup \left(4+\frac 1k, 5.5\right)$, you mean just one open cover, the elements of which are of the form $(-0.5, 1.5) \cup \left(4+\frac 1k, 5.5\right)$, where $k=1,2,3,...$.

Comment: @Mirko Thank you for your constructive comments.

Answer (score 1):

The Heine–Borel theorem states:

For a subset $S$ of the Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$, the following two statements are equivalent:

- $S$ is closed and bounded.
- $S$ is compact, that is, every open cover of $S$ has a finite subcover.

For two distinct real numbers $a<b$, the interval $(a,b]$ is neither open nor closed in $\mathbb R$. The problem point for openness is $b$ since there's no open disc around $b$ which lies entirely in $(a,b]$. The problem point for closedness is $a$ since $a$ is a limit point of $(a,b]$, but is not an element of $(a,b]$.

Therefore, the set $S=[0, 1]\cup (4, 5] $ isn't closed. By Heine–Borel, $S$ is not compact.

Comment: Thank you this answer in particular has clarified it for me.

Comment: If this answer (or any other answer) has helped you then consider accepting/upvoting the answers. If you are finished with the problem then you can close out the question by accepting one of the answers.

Comment: Ok, how do I go about doing that. Apologies, I'm relatively new to this site.

Comment: There is an up arrow on every answer which allows users to give a "thumbs up" for an answer which helps them. Alternatively, there is a  "thumbs down" for an answer which they feel should be improved. To accept an answer, click on check box below the up and down arrows.

Answer (score 0):

The set $$[0, 1]\cup (4, 5]$$ is not compact simply bescause it is not closed.

A compact set in $(\mathbb{R},d)$ is closed and bounded.

You can find an open covering for the set which does not have any finite subcovering. For example consider $$ U_n = (-1/n,1+1/n)\cup (4+1/n,5+1/n), n\ge1$$ which cover the set but does not have any ffinite subcovering for the set.